# Firebase service accounts in menu

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have created a new project on Firebase and i have role owner 

and i can't found service accounts on 'settings project'

how to create it or enable it to get adminsdk private key (file.json)

in other accounts showing service accounts normally 
[image]

but here not showing
[image]

so how to enable it?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly if you need help with the Firebase console.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly why this happened, but you can always manage firebase service accounts on the [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)

My theory is : perhaps you first created this project on the Google Cloud Platform, and then you activated Firebase service.